# Duplicate entry warning in Powershell script while working with IIS?

Tags: powershell, iis

My script is whitelisting IP for a particular URL in IIS.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Name allowUnlisted -Value $false -Location "default web site"
Add-WebConfiguration /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -location "default web site" -Value @{ipAddress = 129.0.0.1 ;subnetmask = 255.255.255.0 ;allowed="true"} -pspath IIS:\
```

It works perfectly except when I remove the entry manually from IIS, and again i try to run this script it warns me "cannot add duplicate entry of type add". I cannot see the entry in IIS. Is there a way to remove that duplicate entry via powershell.

Comment: maybe running `iisreset` will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason behind this is that, applicationhost.config file in inetserv folder has that entry. If you add it via script, remove it via script, or you can open config file in notepad and find the entry and delete it. Save the file after.